# How to pass custom token to multiple Salt MOM?

Tags: salt-stack

I am trying to implement custom authentication with uses my org's Oauth and gets a token which I would like to pass to my Salt Master of Master. I would want that token to be available in my custom auth module (for the purpose of validating it through my org's APIs). Any idea how can I achieve it.

I have followed below documentation already:

[Salt RestCherryPY](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.html#salt.netapi.rest_cherrypy.app.Login)

Comment: What is a MOM ?

Comment: MOM - Master of Master